# firebase firestore permission error not being caught by swift do try catch

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in a swift method that looks to save some data in firestore:

```
do {
    try db.collection("data").document("sample").setData(from: docData)
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

So it works, but I have some firestore security rules that I'm testing and they are also working - allowing writes when it should and denying when they should.  Only problem is that swift is not picking up when the server denies.

If a write is denied, the Xcode log output says:

```
WriteStream Stream error: 'Permission denied: Missing or insufficient permissions.'
Write at ... failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

So it's correctly being rejected because the security rules are being applied correctly, but swift isn't picking it up under `catch`.  I've tried to look this up and looked at the documentation but the Firebase/Firestore documentation hasn't even been updated yet to the new SDK that throws for `setData(from:)`

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the Firestore git for this issue?

Comment: I have but couldn't find anything that's why I posted on here.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the query using the Firestore catch clause instead of the Swift one as shown in this [example in the documentation for Swift](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift):

```swift
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "USA"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```

This way you should be able to handle the error.